# How to retrive basic auth params in spring rest services

Tags: java, spring, basic-authentication

I am using spring rest services in my project. Now i want to enforce basic authentication to the rest services. I am able to do basic authentication but i need the username in that basic auth params. I am unable to extract basic auth params from the request.

Sample URL:

```
http://testusername:testpasword@localhost:7001/sampleApp/rest/test.json
```

After authenticating above url, I need testusername in my service class.

I am using apache LDAP for authentication. So in my application i will not use spring security. But I need basic auth params in my service class.

My Rest class api:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET},
        headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
public String getData() (String userId,HttpServletRequest request) {

    return "test";
}
```

Can some one help me out?

Comment: Please use google before asking - one of many results: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?99363-REST-call-with-Basic-Auth-new-configuration-Spring-3-0-5

Comment: But my problem is retrieving username from basic auth params in service class. I am able to send basic auth params through java client. After authentication i am not able to extract auth param in service class.

Answer (score 0):

How about this guide: [Basic and Digest authentication for a RESTful Service with Spring Security 3.1](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/11/20/basic-and-digest-authentication-for-a-restful-service-with-spring-security-3-1/)